# Bluetooth headphone unable to connect to windows after returning from Ubuntu

Tags: ubuntu, windows, bluetooth

I'm using a dual boot of windows and ubuntu.

I've been using a pair of headphones when i was using windows. Then, i rebooted to ubuntu, successfully connected the bluetooth headphone while in ubuntu.

Now when i returned from ubuntu to windows, i still see the headphone shown as paired, but when i tried to connect with it, it no longer works.

Comment: what is your question?

Comment: why are you posting a Windows problem at a Unix site?